# Trouble converting int to varchar in update

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, integer, varchar

I'm having trouble casting an `int` to `varchar` in an `UPDATE`.

`field1` is an `int` result from a calculated column. I need it to be `varcahr` as I want `'Y'` instead of `'1'`.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET field1 = CAST(field1 AS VARCHAR(1))
UPDATE table1 
SET field1 = CASE WHEN field1 = '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Y' to data type int.

Comment: you aren't casting anything you are trying to update. If `field1` is an INT then `field1` cannot be 'Y' or 'N'y as these are NOT ints. You should just be `select`ing your case expression as a derived column.

Comment: *If* `field1` is a calculated column that isn't the error you would get either; you can't update a calculated column. I would expect you to get the error *"The column "field1" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the column type of `field1` you'll see SQL Server is storing it as an `int`

If you want to store a varchar value you'll have to add a new varchar column to the table

`ALTER TABLE table1 ADD vfield varchar(1)`

Then update the newly added text column

`UPDATE table 1 SET vfield = CASE WHEN field1 = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END`

This is causing redundancy in your table and you should consider using a view or looking at how the output is being formatted.

It would be more efficient to store a Y/N value as a bit type column (1,0) and format it dynamically as 'Yes' or 'No' in your visualisation tool